# Remotely configure Android TV brightness with ADB Shell

Tags: android, adb

#### Environment

- I have a Sony X850G 55" Android TV
- I've enabled remote debugging over USB/Wi-Fi
- I've connected ADB to the device's IP address
- I want to remotely set the display brightness using ADB

#### What I've Tried

```
adb shell settings put system screen_brightness 30
adb shell settings put system screen_brightness 255
```

#### Actual Result

Nothing happens.

#### Expected Result

The screen brightness changes according to my setting.

**Question**: How can I remotely configure the screen brightness of my Android TV, using ADB, or a similar utility / API?

Comment: Just FYI: Screen brightness may be under the control of a OEM/ODM app in addition to other custom modes (movie/sports/etc.), https://source.android.com/devices/tv/customize-tv-app

Answer (score 1):

Someone on Reddit pointed me to the [Sony REST API](https://pro-bravia.sony.net/develop/integrate/rest-api/spec/service/video/v1_0/setPictureQualitySettings/index.html) for the Bravia TVs. The REST API listens on port 80.

1. Get the IP address of your TV from the Settings menu
2. Enable Pre-Shared Key (PSK) authentication under Settings --> Network & Internet --> Home Network --> IP control --> Authentication
3. Create a PSK under Settings --> Network & Internet --> Home Network --> IP control --> Pre-Shared Key
4. Set the PSK and IP in the script below

```
$Headers = @{
  'X-Auth-PSK' = '123123'
}

$TVIP = '192.168.1.199'

$Body = @{
  method = 'setPictureQualitySettings'
  version = '1.0'
  id = 12
  params = @(
    @{
      settings = @(
        @{
          target = 'brightness'
          value = '50'
        }
      )
    }
  )
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 6

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://$TVIP/sony/video -Body $Body -Headers $Headers -Method POST
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation about this around the web, but thanks to another stack overflow topic, I known that you can do dumpsys settings and search values from there. So I put the TV brightness to something "organic" like 97% for searching it using grep, and immediately found the right setting to change for my Hitachi.
This adb shell command did the trick for me:

> settings put global picture_backlight 5

(this sets 5 percent)